# Synchronize folders using MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild, task, synchronization

How can I use MSBuildExtensionPack 's Sync task to replace all files that exist in folder A with copies in folder B? (but skip any files that only exist in B?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple

Use "Exclude" and "!Exists" when defining the list of files to be copied

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use extension pack? If that is not a requirement, you can just do it using xcopy:

```
<Exec Command="xcopy /yu $(SourceFolder) $(DestinationFolder)" />
```

Make sure $(DestinationFolder) already exists before executing this, otherwise xcopy will be displaying a prompt to create one, which is not useful for the automated build system.